# Finding the power series representation for $f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{2x-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

[image]

So with this question in particular, it has a blank space before the series, which implies that there should be a value added to it? I know how to find the power series but considering that there is a blank space before the summation, I'm a little confused.

Comment: I suggest you use long division first

Comment: Try using the geometric series $1/(1-a) = 1+a+a^2+a^3+\cdots$ with $a=2x$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$
x^2 +1 = \frac{x}{2}(2x-1) + \frac{2x-1}{4} + \frac{5}{4} 
$$
So using the geometric series formula [$-\sum_{n\ge 0} r^n = \frac{1}{r-1}$ when $|r| <1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) we get
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+1}{2x-1} &= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{5}{4} \frac{1}{\color{blue}{2x}-1}\\
& =\frac{x}{2} +\frac{1}{4}- \frac{5}{4} \sum_{n \ge \color{red}{0}} (\color{blue}{2x})^n\\
& =\frac{x}{2} +\frac{1}{4} -\frac{5}{4} (1+2x) - \sum_{n \ge \color{red}{2}} \frac{5}{4}2^n x^n\\
\end{align}
Can you finish simplifying from here?

Comment: Then we'd get that x/2 + 1/4 + 5/(8x-4) is equivalent to the original equation, however I still don't understand what this would do to further the steps. Is 1/4 not necessary in the summation? Is that what to fill the blank in with? Because I've already tried x/2 + 1/4 in the blank before.

Comment: @kuulstorybro, I've added more details to the answer. Hope it helps!